# Typescript class instance to javascript object

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my code:

```
class A{
    test: string
    constructor(test: string){
        this.test = test
    }
}
const a = new A("hi")
console.log(a)
```

This is my output:

> A { test: 'hi' }

When I want to upload this as a Javascript object, it get's rejected because it ain't a Javascript object. I can make one by doing this:

```
const someJSON = JSON.stringify(a)
const javascriptObject = JSON.parse(someJSON)
```

But I think there must be a better way, this feels like a hack. How to convert a typescript class instance to a plain javascript object?

Comment: A typescript class instance *is* a javascript object. You see that on the console because that is the way Chrome outputs it: `Type object`.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It isn't true. When I print typeof === 'object' on my instance, it is false. After the parse, it prints true

Comment: It is true. If you do `a instanceof Object` it returns  `true`. `typeof "hello"` outputs `string`, not object, and yet is a valid JavaScript object

Comment: If you need a vanilla JavaScript object, use vanilla JavaScript. Doesn't seem like a complicated conundrum.

Comment: `I want to upload this as a Javascript object, it get's rejected` <= What exactly do you mean by `"upload as a javascript object"` and what do you mean by `"rejected"`? What does rejected mean? Is there an error message? If so please post it.

Comment: @Igor I use firebase cloud functions to put in the object in my database. This is my error message: 'Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object.'  It is a valid object after the stringfy and parse

Comment: Then this is a firebase specific issue. See also this "duplicate" [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1215). In the future it helps to have context. Adding what you have above in your comment makes it much easier to understand by those reading through your question.

Comment: Of course this is not a TS issue; the types only matter for compilation.

Comment: @Igor the problem is, my typescript isn't a object. When I do a check e.g. === 'object', it prints out false.

Comment: @Igor - can't get through can you!! --- The issue is not related to TS, an Object, or a Class Instance. It is a fundamental understanding of what **Firebase requires** in the form of a valid document.  The OP needs to think about the **Firebase** document as an **object literal** rather than trying to store an instantiated object. Igor's reference to the [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1215) does describe a similar issue.

Comment: @OscarPaz "hello" is not a JavaScript object. It is a string. `new String("hello")` is an object, but for that reason `typeof new String("hello") === "object"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) to set the prototype of your symbol explicitly to the default prototype of objects, which is [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype):

```js
class A {
    constructor(test) {
        this.test = test
    }
}

const a = new A("hi")
Object.setPrototypeOf(a, Object.prototype);
console.log({ a, proto: Object.getPrototypeOf(a) });
```

This will make `a` equal to `{ test: "hi" }`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a plain JS object instead of a class instance you can spread the properties for example:

```js
class A{
    constructor(test){
        this.test = test
    }
}
const a = new A("hi");
const b = { ...a };

console.log('a:', a);
console.log('b:', b);
console.log('Is b instance of A:', b instanceof A);
```

Comment: So your answer is to use vanilla JavaScript then? I agree!

Comment: @RandyCasburn: Well, this question is not specific to TypeScript in that types are not the issue. (And vanilla JS is executable as snippet, so...)

Comment: The OP uses types in his example - and that **is** the reason it cannot be used directly. But I still agree with you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add methods to your class in future, 
some properties may become private. So add a method toObject. Then you will be able to use methods and provide data to api in needed format.

```
class A{
      constructor(private _test: string){

      }

      public toObject(){
        //return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));
        //in case if you want to have underscored private
        let object = {};
        Object.keys(this).map((key: string) => {
          object[key.slice(1)] = this[key];
        });

        return object;
      }
    }

    const a = new A("hi")
    console.log(a);
    console.log('----------------------');
    console.log(a.toObject());
```